# Getting the error "Next.js unmet peer dependency error " when installing next.js app

Tags: next.js, dependencies, node-modules, yarnpkg

So , when I'm trying to create a new Next.js app using `npx create-next-app@latest todo-app` command , I get this following error while It's being installed :

> "eslint-config-next > @typescript-eslint/parser > @typescript-eslint/typescript-estree > tsutils@3.21.0" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".

After the installation , when I try to run the app using `yarn dev` (I also tried `npm run dev` but to no avail) , It won't work and I get this following error :

```
./node_modules/next/dist/client/dev/amp-dev.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'F:\{folder names}\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js' in 'F:\{folder names}\node_modules\next\dist\client\dev'
[DEP_WEBPACK_MODULE_ISSUER] DeprecationWarning: Module.issuer: Use new ModuleGraph API
```

I also get lot more errors after this error , so I'm just going to add image of them.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you responding with **No** when the `create-next-app` CLI tool asks if you would like to use Typescript? I see the same issue when choosing **No**. If Typescript is required even when you select **No** so it generates **.js** source files instead of **.ts** then it should install that dependency anyway. It feels like a logic flaw in the CLI tool.

As it is you will have to add it manually with your package manager of choice:

```
npm install typescript --save-dev

yarn add typescript --dev

pnpm add typescript -D
```

I think your other errors may be related to spaces used in your project folder hierarchy though I'm not sure. Maybe look at renaming your `00.React projects` folder?